# Add js in all pages (prestashop)

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to add js file in all pages prestashop 1.1.0 ?

I am not sure if i need to add page.tpl file in theme to & then add script code in it.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

At yout file `/themes/classic/templates/_partials/head.tpl` you can add your `<script>script.js</script>`, but in prestashop the best way to add a custom script is adding it to `/themes/classic/assets/js/custom.js`